# How can I display \n as new lines in multitail?

Tags: php, debugging, multitail

I am using multitail to monitor logs while I program. I really like this tool. However, it is hard to use it to view object output in a php error log because new line characters `\n` are not processed. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: On idea that I'd had was to use the regex to do a replace, but I think that's not possible here.

Answer (score 1):

combining [the answer for tail](https://serverfault.com/questions/126407/display-n-characters-as-newlines-when-using-tail):

```
tail -f file | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

with the -l option in multitail:

```
multitail -l "tail -f file | sed 's/\\\n/\\n/g'"
```

note: the additional escape on the \n

extra hint: 
(will color all files and merge them into one multitail window):

```
multitail -C fileUNfiltered -L "tail -f file | sed 's/\\\n/\\n/g'"
```